# Moveit! integration with Jaco arm ISSUE

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have been trying to integrate Moveit! with a real arm (Jaco2 from Kinova) for almost a MONTH now! and I haven't made any progress since I finished the tutorials. I can get everything (planning, obstacle avoidance etc.) working in simulation from the tutorials but I haven't really figured out how to get it working with a real arm. For now my aim is to get the real robot in rviz, plan a path using Moveit! and execute it via the real arm. I can get bits and pieces of information from the internet scattered everywhere but the whole picture is still not clear. Also because I think I do not know ROS super well.

This is what I have been doing as per my understanding.
After finishing all the tutorials and creating the jaco_moveit_config folder from the Moveit! setup assistant I launch the real robot, `roslaunch kinova_bringup kinova_robot.launch`. The ros package for the kinova Jaco arm that I am using is [here](https://github.com/Kinovarobotics/kinova-ros).

I then create the [jaco_controllers.yaml](https://github.com/radhen/learning_moveit_jaco/blob/master/jaco_moveit_config/config/jaco_controllers.yaml) file and [moveit_planning_execution.launch](https://github.com/radhen/learning_moveit_jaco/blob/master/jaco_moveit_config/launch/moveit_planning_execution.launch) file as mentioned [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/192739/implement-moveit-on-real-robot/). I also create a [jaco_moveit_simple_controller_manager.launch](https://github.com/radhen/learning_moveit_jaco/blob/master/jaco_moveit_config/launch/jaco_moveit_controller_manager.launch) file as mentioned [here](https://github.com/JenniferBuehler/jaco-arm-pkgs/wiki/Setup-Jaco-with-MoveIt).

After that I `roslaunch jaco_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch` and get the following errors,

> FATAL
> ros.moveit_ros_planning.traj_execution:
> Parameter '~moveit_controller_manager'
> not specified. This is needed to
> identify the plugin to use for
> interacting with controllers. No paths
> can be executed.

and following warnings

> WARN ros.moveit_ros_planning: No
> transform available between frame
> 'j2n6a300_end_effector' and planning
> frame '/robot_root' ()   WARN
> ros.moveit_ros_planning: No transform
> available between frame
> 'j2n6a300_link_6' and planning frame
> '/robot_root' ()
>
> WARN ros.moveit_ros_planning: No
> transform available between frame
> 'j2n6a300_link_base' and planning
> frame '/robot_root' ()
>
> WARN ros.moveit_ros_planning: No
> transform available between frame
> 'root' and planning frame
> '/robot_root' ()
>
> WARN ros.moveit_ros_planning: No
> transform available between frame
> 'j2n6a300_link_finger_tip_1' and
> planning frame '/robot_root' ()
>
> WARN ros.moveit_ros_planning: No
> transform available between frame
> 'j2n6a300_link_finger_1' and planning
> frame '/robot_root' ()
>
> WARN ros.moveit_ros_planning: No
> transform available between frame
> 'j2n6a300_link_finger_tip_2' and
> planning frame '/robot_root' ()
>
> WARN ros.moveit_ros_planning: No
> transform available between frame
> 'j2n6a300_link_finger_2' and planning
> frame '/robot_root' ()

After which when I try `roslaunch jaco_moveit_config jaco_moveit_controller_manager.launch` the process dies
saying

> shutting down processing monitor....

Is the sequence of launching things wrong?
My belief is that these three things are sufficient to see the real arm in rviz in real time and plan and execute some motions. Also note I would not need any action servers at this point as I am not executing any trajectories on the real arm. (correct me here if I am wrong)

The issue I think might be is that the joint names in the urdf that I have and the names in the rosparam server does not match. That's why I get stuck in errors and warnings all the time regarding the mismatch in joint names.

Can anyone please go through my files and point out the mistakes I am making? I am happy to share my files on [git](https://github.com/radhen/learning_moveit_jaco). Feel free to check them out. Also if you need to look at some errors or any other stuff please ask.

Thank you for reading!

P.S. [Dr. Dave Coleman](https://github.com/davetcoleman) one of the lead developers of Moveit! recently graduated from our lab and has been travelling so sadly could not get much help from him.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250493/moveit!-integration-with-jaco-arm-issue/) by [rdhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20187/rdhn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-12-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-21**:
Could you please clearly dscribe what the problems are you encounter? I think they're in there, but it's hard to be sure as your problem description is rather vague.

**Comment by [rdhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20187/rdhn/) on 2016-12-21**:
Thank you for responding to my question. I have edited my question and added the errors and warnings that I am getting. Can you please guide me now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like the namespace is misconfigured for `Parameter '~moveit_controller_manager' not specified.`. Try:

```
rosparam list | grep moveit_controller_manager
```

To determine if you are loading that parameter in a different namespace than the node you are launching.

Also, try one of my Jaco2 implementations in simulation: https://github.com/correlllab/jaco_cu/

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2016-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rdhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20187/rdhn/) on 2016-12-22**:
rosparam list | grep moveit_controller_manager gives me */moveit_controller_manager* as the output. Nothing else. Not sure if this is what we want!?